# Gradle tasks that depends on custom configuration

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to convert a build.gradle into kotlin  dsl. Earlier I had a custom configuration sourceset and configuration

```
       configurations { dashboard } 
       sourceSets { dashboard }
```

and within dependecies block I had defined like this

```
    dependencies{
           dashboardImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36'
           dashboardImplementation"com.grafana:dashboard-generator-core:0.0.1"
    
    }
```

and I had a custom task that was using these dependencies like this

```
    task generateDashboard(group: 'dashboard', description: 'generate dashboard json', type: JavaExec, dependsOn: "dashboardClasses") {
        mainClass = "com.grafana.GenerateDashboard"
        classpath = sourceSets.dashboard.runtimeClasspath
    }
```

The way I have made similar changes in kotlin dsl

```
 val dashboard by configurations.creating
    
 val dashboardSourceSet = sourceSets.create("dashboard")
```

```
dependencies{
    dashboard("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36")
    dashboard("com.grafana:dashboard-generator-core:0.0.1")
    
}
```

and a custom task as

```
     tasks.register<JavaExec>("generateDashboard") {
            group = "dashboard"
            dependsOn("dashboardClasses")
            main = "com.grafana.GenerateDashboard"
            classpath = sourceSets[dashboardSourceSet.name].runtimeClasspath
            
        }
```

However I get error when dependencies are not resolved for this task. Not sure why dependeNcies are not resolved with dashboard configuration

Comment: What's the full error message? What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: I am using gradle 7.4.1. Essentially its not able to resolve main class `com.grafana.GenerateDashboard` which is part of this dependency `com.grafana:dashboard-generator-core:0.0.1`. I am wondering earlier I used to have `dashboardImplementation` . Whats the equivalent in kotlin dsl when you want your dependencies to resolve only for test or implementation

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong from a small summary of an error code, can you put the full error in your question?

Comment: `> Task : generateDashboard FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class com.grafana.GenerateDashboard
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.grafana.GenerateDashboard`

How do we define scope with custom configuration? My hunch is around that @aSemy